# Conditionally load properties files in Ant

Tags: ant

My Ant script should download a ZIP file which contains a set-up file to be installed in a database (Oracle or PostgreSQL) and generate dumps. Different dumps are generated depending on the properties data provided in the set up file.

I have 3 properties files:

1. user.properties : this contains various details provided from Jenkins and apart from that a value: `prepare.MTdump.generate=true`
2. nonMT.properties
3. MT.properties

Is it possible in Ant to load the first properties file `user.properties` and depending upon the condition (e.g. if `prepare.MTdump.generate=true`) load `MT.properties` or if it's false load `nonMT.properties`?

I have been unable to add an IF condition to load the properties file. I even tried with the `unless` condition of `<target>` but have been unable to achieve the requirement.

Comment: Please add what you have tried. It is very much possible to load the file conditionally.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ant-contrib, this should work:

```
<property file="user.properties"/>
<if>
    <equals arg1="${prepare.MTdump.generate}" arg2="true"/>
    <then>
        <property file="MT.properties"/>
    </then>
    <else>
        <property file="nonMT.properties"/>
    </else>
</if>
```

Otherwise, you can just use conditions. Just run the loadProperties target below.

```
<property file="user.properties"/>

<target name="test.if.use.MT">
    <condition property="useMT">
        <equals arg1="${prepare.MTdump.generate}" arg2="true"/>
    </condition>
    <condition property="useNonMT">
        <not>
            <equals arg1="${prepare.MTdump.generate}" arg2="true"/>
        </not>
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="loadMTProperties" if="${useMT}" depends="test.if.use.MT">
    <property file="MT.properties"/>
</target>

<target name="loadNonMTProperties" if="${useNonMT}" depends="test.if.use.MT">
    <property file="nonMT.properties"/>
</target>

<target name="loadProperties" depends="loadMTProperties, loadNonMTProperties"/>
```